# SQL Create Table command not functioning

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE artist
(
    aid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(40),
    dob DATE,
    gender CHAR(1)
);
```

I've tried putting it all on one line. I've tried messing with capitalization, and I get the same error message which is

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/919cd)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With database questions, it is a good idea to also include your database type and version in the tags. I updated the question tags to include `MySQL`. If that is incorrect, please [update them](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16822425/edit) ).

Answer (score 5):

You have to execute this command in the database (not from the command line).

For example, if you are using MySQL, you have to [login to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200215/how-to-log-in-to-mysql-and-query-the-database-from-linux-terminal) first:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

then enter the password. You'll see a welcome screen and a `mysql>` prompt:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8 to server version: 3.23.28-gamma-log

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer

mysql>
```

Type `CREATE TABLE` command after the `mysql>` prompt.