# MySQL Error 1044/1045 Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying

```
mysql -u mlimon -p
```

Then input the password it successfully login to the MySQL but when I'm trying something like this

```
mysql -umlimon -pmySqlPassword
```

Or

```
mysql -u mlimon -p mySqlPassword
```

OR

```
mysql -umlimon -p <<MY_QUERY
USE mysql
SHOW tables
MY_QUERY
```

It's returning

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mlimon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" Or something Error 1044 Access denied

My main intention to run some query in shell script but if I can't login directly to the database it's won't run and when I'm trying to pass the password it's showing access denied. but my question is why it's working when I'm imputing the password in command separately and not working with other way?

NOTE: my password contain a dollar sign, so is this something make the difference here?

Comment: Has this user been associated with this database?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415371/how-to-escape-dollar-sign-in-mysql-when-executed-by-command-line) may be of interest re dollar sign

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign an existing user to mysql databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199557/assign-an-existing-user-to-mysql-databases)

Comment: Please remove the ```sql-server``` tag as that is different than mysql

Comment: @Martin actually mlimon is a root user like everyone has root username. So, i'm trying to create new user and database from shell script here. normall mysql login working fine but when i'm passing password for run -e directly it's showing this error

Comment: @Bee_Riii that actually just an example it's not the make the different here