# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have downloaded a repo on github and created a database. I am trying to do migrations and am getting the below error

Error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Tafuta
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:0IDLuBYdTssK55SeeQTmCJ3GHlJXsR6BahTeenXaf90=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=TafutaM
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: execute: 'php artisan config:cache',  and try again

Comment: where is your .env file ? how is your project structure ? its seems laravle is not reading your .env file

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the following command if you downloaded the source from GitHub:

```
composer install
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.env` is not taken into consideration for the variables.

It might be cause by something in your `Vhost configuration` like

- A direct declaration of the variable in there that would override `.env` variables.
- Another `environment file` is declared it it to be read. like `.env.prod` or `.env.dev`

Answer (score 0):

Many people have this common error: It's because your database is not set.

Error say: '@localhost', then username = ''
database: forge, then database is named = 'forge'

If you dont see that parameters into your .env, its because file is not read, then you have to refresh your configuration:

`php artisan config:cache`

if you are using `php artisan serve` cancel it, and run again.

Now, if problem persists, you have to log with terminal or a database tool to your database, and make sure that the next parameters are the same:

```
DB_CONNECTION=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Sometimes, people set incorrect port, or username or any(dont forget refresh configuration if you edit .env file).

Comment: how do i log to the database with the terminal

Comment: this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200215/how-to-log-in-to-mysql-and-query-the-database-from-linux-terminal